# Integrating social networks authentication. Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, owin, social-networking, dotnetopenauth

I have an existing Asp.Net MVC solution and want to implement authentication using social networks like Twitter, Facebook.
 
Which is the best way of implementation?

---

I know two ways: use DotNetOpenAuth which is not actual nowadays or use the newest OWIN. But owin demands IdentityContext, and it is a problem because now project runs an ordinary DbContext. 
I'm looking for the simpliest way of implementing this. 
Does anybody know any other solution?